# Retrofit null response и call

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Всем привет, проблема связанна не знаю сам с чем, пытался сделать супер-легкое приложение с retrofit 2 на андроиде и столкнулся с проблемой что данные не приходят ко мне.

Модель приложения

```
package com.danielstrelnikov.simpleretrofit.Model;

import android.util.Log;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class Model {
    private static Model mInstance;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
    private Retrofit mRetrofit;

    private Model() {
        mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public static Model getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new Model();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public JSONPlaceHolderApi getJSONApi() {
        Log.d("TAG", "getJSONApi: " + mRetrofit.baseUrl());
        return mRetrofit.create(JSONPlaceHolderApi.class);
    }
}
```

Интерфейс для retrofit

```
package com.danielstrelnikov.simpleretrofit.Model;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;

public interface JSONPlaceHolderApi {
    @GET("posts/{id}")
    public Call<Post> getPostWithId(@Path("id") int id);

    @GET("posts")
    public Call<ArrayList<Post>> getAllPost();
}
```

Класс для получения инфы

```
package com.danielstrelnikov.simpleretrofit.Model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Post {

    @SerializedName("userId")
    @Expose
    private Integer userId;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("body")
    @Expose
    private String body;

    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

}
```

тут вот вылетает null на body и call

```
package com.danielstrelnikov.simpleretrofit.Presenter;

import com.danielstrelnikov.simpleretrofit.Model.Model;
import com.danielstrelnikov.simpleretrofit.Model.Post;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class Presenter {
    String sPost = "";
    int showPost = 0;

    private String getPost(int id){
        Model.getInstance()
                .getJSONApi()
                .getPostWithId(id)
                .enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
                Post post = response.body();
                sPost += post.getTitle() + "\n"
                        + post.getBody() + "\n"
                        + post.getId() + "\n"
                        + post.getUserId();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
                sPost = "";
                sPost = "Error occurred while getting request!";
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        return sPost;
    }

    public String setPostOnView(){
        return getPost(showPost);
    }


}
```

Ошибка из лога

```
      --------- beginning of crash
03-27 13:34:28.951 1820-1820/com.danielstrelnikov.simpleretrofit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.danielstrelnikov.simpleretrofit, PID: 1820
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.danielstrelnikov.simpleretrofit.Model.Post.getTitle()' on a null object reference
        at com.danielstrelnikov.simpleretrofit.Presenter.Presenter$1.onResponse(Presenter.java:22)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:71)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Если навести мышку на Call или Response в методе enqueue

```
Not annotated parameter overrides @EverythingIsNonNull parameter more... (Ctrl+F1)
```

Совсем не понимаю в чем проблема так как только начал учить retrofit 2, спасибо за помощь

Comment: Выложите пожалуйста Ваш код в виде текста, а не картинок.

Comment: Я не вижу чтобы у вас что-то где-то "вылетало". Запустите, приведите трейс запроса и ошибки, если возникает.

Comment: Ну вот, да, как @EugeneKrivenja и заметил, тут не видно где и как вылетает с NPE. По поводу "не приходят данные", так http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/0 - возвращает пустой json, идентификатор статьи, он же у вас `showPost` равен 0. Попробуйте с `showPost = 1`.

Comment: Спасибо, и вправду пустой ответ, а почему же оно не кидает в onFailure?

Comment: Пустой ответ, это не ошибка. Это пустой, но корректный ответ.

Comment: Раскидайте по методам лоои, посмотрите что уходит что приходит что бы понимать куда идти